# Saving output of command to variable, ": command not found"

Tags: bash

I am creating a script that will kill a task when my available RAM is below a certain value. For this I have this command that obtains the amount of RAM left. When I display it, I get a number "154372822" for example, but when I save it to a variable through $() it has that number with a: ": command not found" attached onto it.

Once I have this "var1" I wish to pass it into an if statement.

% Here is the issue line of code.

```
var1=$(awk -v low=$(grep low /proc/zoneinfo | awk '{k+=$2}END{print k}') \ '{a[$1]=$2} END{print a["MemFree:"]+a["Active(file):"]+a["Inactive(file):"]+a["SReclaimable:"]-(12*low);}' /proc/meminfo)

if [var1 -lt 1*1000*1000]; then
         echo "Memory exceeded"
         kill -9 $var2
         break
else
```

Comment: I think you can solve this problem by pasting your script in www.shellcheck.net

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Missing spaces around test command...

Comment: Don't use two awks and a grep when one awk will do: `var1=$(awk 'FNR == NR && /low/ {low += $2; next} {a[$1]=$2} END {print a["MemFree:"] + a["Active(file):"] + a["Inactive(file):"] + a["SReclaimable:"] - (12 * low)}' /proc/zoneinfo /proc/meminfo)`. If you're using Bash, then use the features it provides: `if (( var1 < 1*1000*1000))` - this is an integer comparison in an arithmetic context so your multiplication will actually work. Don't use `kill -9` except as a last resort. It doesn't allow processes to clean up after themselves. Try `kill` first, then after waiting briefly, if the...

Comment: ...process is still running, then perhaps try `kill -9`.

Answer (score 0):

`if [[ "$var1" -lt 1000000 ]]` - see [conditionals](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals).